# Scaling on separate charts - pinescript

Tags: pine-script

Charting BTC and added a separate chart to to show MACD.  Looking good so far.

Now I want to add a shape to identify buy/sell alerts:

```
//plotshape(buy_signal, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), text = "B", location = location.abovebar)
```

When I add this line it rescales the chart  - which was previously scaled to the ranges in the MACD output - to the scale of the primary (BTC)chart; 0-20,000 at present - so the MACD data which ranges +-20 disappears to a flat line at the base of the chart.

How do I add the plotshape but maintain the scale in the second chart so that the plots are relative to the MACD values not the main chart's BTC values?

Alternatively can I plot them in the main chart despite being calculated for a script in a separate chart?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `location.abovebar`, you can use `location.absolute`. This way you can specify a specific price level where the shapes will be displayed.

> Alternatively can I plot them in the main chart despite being
> calculated for a script in a separate chart?

Sure. Just do the same calculations in your main script but don't plot anything from the one in a separate chart.

Comment: Sorry it's taken a while to get back..  I ended up following both your suggestions.  plotshape(BuySignal ? close : na, style = shape.triangleup, color=color.new(color.lime, 0), text = "LO", location = location.abovebar) - specifically adding 'close' so that it followed the main price chart.